# MVVMcross Command Binding fire Exception

Tags: mvvmcross, uwp

I experience an issue when i try to use a command to open a Second View Model **V4.0.Beta5**.
I followed the Exemple described in N+1 Video series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W

First ViewModel

```
public class FirstViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross";

    public string Hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set
        {
            _hello = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello);
        }
    }

    private Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand _goSecondViewCommand;

    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand GoSecondViewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _goSecondViewCommand = _goSecondViewCommand ??
                                   new Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand(DoGoSecondView);
            return _goSecondViewCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DoGoSecondView()
    {
        base.ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Second View model

```
public class SecondViewModel :MvxViewModel
{
    private string _hello2 = "Hello2 MvvmCross";

    public string Hello2
    {
        get { return _hello2; }
        set
        {
            _hello2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello2);
        }
    }
}
```

First View

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
x:Class="TestCommand.UWP.Views.FirstView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestCommand.UWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="FirstView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding GoSecondViewCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="108" Margin="70,346,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
</Grid>
```

Second view

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
x:Class="TestCommand.UWP.Views.SecondView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestCommand.UWP.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid />
```

Setup Class:

```
    public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
    public Setup(Frame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new TestCommand.Core.App();
    }
}
```

If you want you can download the solution Here:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A5D9789788DE33CB!36079&authkey=!AKs9nsG28iI6nQQ&ithint=file%2czip.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: e = {Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs} --> Exception = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Do you have a SecondView defined? (you're only showing the first view)

Comment: Yes, I have the second view defined. (I updated my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason is you don't use Setup correctly in your UWP app, here is what I do to make this work:

**1)** Create two ViewModels in the UWP app: FirstViewModel and SecondViewModel

**2)** Create a Setup class in `Setup.cs` file:

```
public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
        public Setup(Frame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
        {
        }

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            return new AppSetup();
        }
}

public class AppSetup : MvxApplication
{
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            RegisterAppStart<FirstViewModel>();
        }
}
```

**3)** FirstView.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="FirstView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
        <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Hello}" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding GoSecondViewCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**4)** SecondView.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SecondView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
        <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding Hello2}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**5)** In `App.xaml.cs` file, make the following changes in `OnLaunched` method:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{

......

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                var setup = new Setup(rootFrame);
                setup.Initialize();

                var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
                start.Start();
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

**By the way, the MvvmCross version is 3.5.1**

**Check the Completed sample on [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/MVVMCrossUWPApp1/MVVMCrossUWPApp1)**

---

**Update for exception in `OnNavigationFailed` method:**

Please comment this line in FirstView and SecondView's code behind:

```
ViewModel = new FirstViewModel();

ViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
```

The MvvmCross has set the ViewModel automatically.

Comment: I updated my code (Only setup was different). an i get the error when the application start:
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failed to load Page TestCommand.UWP.Views.FirstView
  Source=TestCommand.UWP
  StackTrace:
       at TestCommand.UWP.App.OnNavigationFailed(Object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
  InnerException:

Comment: Where did you Initialize the Setup? Could you share your demo using OneDrive?

Comment: Added at the end of my original post.